# Why regarded as partial specialized

Tags: c++, templates, g++

Having the following code, I am somewhat confused why the second `foo` is regarded as a partial specialization, while the latter is not (IMO both should not be *partial*).

```
template <bool IS_TRUE>
int foo();

// Doesn't work!?
template <bool IS_TRUE>
int foo<IS_TRUE>() {
    return 0;
}

template <>
int foo<true>() {
    return 0;
}

int main() {
    return foo<true>();
}
```

On the second `foo` gcc complains:

> error: function template partial specialization ‘foo’ is not
>   allowed

Can someone please explain, what details I am missing.

Comment: A primary template definition is not allowed to have a template-argument-list (the `<IS_TRUE>` part) because it would look exactly like a partial specialization (remember, classes can have that). And since function templates can't have partial specializations...

Comment: Really? These 2 definitions look pretty different to me. Do you have a link to the spec?

Comment: `§14.5/1`: "A *template-id*, that is, the *template-name* followed by a *template-argument-list* shall not be specified in the declaration of a primary template declaration."

Answer (score 0):

The syntax with template-arguments after the name is reserved for partial specialization:

```
template<typename T> struct foo {};
template<typename T> struct foo<T *> {};
```

If a partial specialization fails to specialize any arguments you'll get an error like this:

```
template<typename T> struct foo {};
template<typename T> struct foo<T> {};
error: partial specialization 'foo<T>' does not specialize any template arguments
```

Partial specialization is not allowed for function templates (use overloads instead), so there's no point the compiler checking whether the specialization actually specializes any template arguments; it's illegal in any case.  If you're separating the declaration and definition of the function, you should omit the template arguments in both declaration and definition:

```
template<bool IS_TRUE> int foo();
template<bool IS_TRUE> int foo() { return 0; }
template<> int foo<true>() { return 0; }
```